# What happens with static variables when android application is fully destroyed and service is still running. Are they become null or not

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to make a android music application. I don't know that static variable become null or not if application killed from background while service class still running.

Comment: Static fields will "become `null`" when your process is terminated and then later restarted. So long as your process is running, only your own code will affect static fields.

Comment: I will ask more questions as they come into my mind. Looking forward for more help. Thanks.